# I need to initialize the Application class based on the environment the user is logging into, Live or Beta?

Tags: android, android-application-class, instabug

I am integrating Instabug into an Application, and Instabug needs to be initialized in the Application class. But, The Environment(Live or Beta) the user is logging in will only be known once the user logs in. And Instabug integration requires you to provide the API token for the particular Environment. Since we don't know which environment the user is logging in, I can't instantiate Instabug in `Application` class. Is there a workaround?

Comment: If you make a manifest entry for application class of the `Application` will be instantiate automatically . So workaround is check inside application class before  initializing Instabug.

Answer (score 0):

let's break it down into two issues

1- "Instabug needs to be initialized in the Application class. But, The Environment(Live or Beta) the user is logging in will only be known once the user logs in."

As per my understanding, you only need to disable and enable Instabug at runtime.
Which is easily doable by initializing Instabug in the application class normally and you can disable it right after the initialization using this API `Instabug.disable();`

In case  you want to enable Instabug later, you can do that by calling `Instabug.enable();` at runtime. 
(in your case right after users sign up).

2- regarding the beta or live, you can ship your APK with Instabug initialized using the beta-token and whenever you want to release a live APK you can use the live-token and ship your release to Google Play.

Comment: OR using build flavors instead.

Comment: I am aware of this solution, but this doesn't work for our app. I need to initialize it after the login with the live or beta token.